# redshift-gtk crashes on start, ImportError: No module named 'xdg'

Tags: python, gtk, mint, redshift

I'm getting the following error whenever I try to run `redshift-gtk`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/redshift-gtk", line 26, in <module>
    from redshift_gtk.statusicon import run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redshift_gtk/statusicon.py", line 38, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redshift_gtk/utils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from xdg import BaseDirectory as base
ImportError: No module named 'xdg'
```

And I was unable to find any solution on internets, so maybe somebody here could help me out? Simple `redshift` seems to work though. Or it would if I provided it with valid arguments.

The OS:

Linux Mint 17.2 KDE edition.

Comment: Questions about Mint are [not on-topic here](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). You may want to move this to the [Linux & Unix StackExchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a Python dependency. Install it with `sudo apt-get install python3-xdg`. I [just checked](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/python3-xdg), it is included in Ubuntu Wily. If it is not included in your version of Linux Mint, you can install it by downloading it from the [mentioned site](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/python3-xdg) and installing it with `sudo dpkg -i …` manually.

In case there is some Python egg on PyPI, you can install it the with `pip3 install xdg`. In case you do not have `pip3`, it should tell you how to install it when you try to start `pip`.

Comment: Yes, I would appreciate it since `python3-redshift` wasn't found in my repositories.

Comment: Are you sure `python3-redshift` is even a thing? Couldn't find it anywhere and `pip3 install xdg` won't work:

    Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement xdg

Comment: `python3-redshift` is not a thing, I meant `python3-xdg`. The Ubuntu package is now linked, you could force-install the Ubuntu package on Linux Mint to get the package. It seems that `xdg` is not directly a package on PyPI then. Fedora has `python3-pyxdg` and `pyxdg` packages. Perhaps `pip3` can find `pyxdg`?

Comment: `apt-get install python3-xdg` did the trick, however `redshift-gtk` won't start still. It ceased to throw any exceptions and even seem to start process but then just exits without warning.

Comment: Does it do anything when you start it with `--help`?

Comment: Nope. Parameters or not, it won't start.

Comment: If there is no output at all, I am afraid I cannot help you any further. You can try to contact the programmers of the program and the maintainers of the package. You can see the maintainer with `apt-get show PACKAGENAME`.

Comment: @Moorindal Talk about it on the official Linux Mint chat [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32504/linux-mint) or the unofficial chat [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32292/we-need-linux-mint-on-se).